# Need to change this subquery to a join? (LINQ/T-SQL/EF)

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

So I have an EmployeeScheduleRoles table, containing ID, EmployeeID, ScheduleID, RoleID

As a note, RoleID == 1 means you're an admin (manager) of that schedule.
I hard-coded the manager's ID to be 15921

Right now, I grab the schedules that the manager has jurisdiction to

```
var schedList1 = (
  from esr in dbcontext.EmployeeScheduleRoles
  where esr.EmployeeID == 15921 && esr.RoleID == 1
  select esr);
```

From here, I grab all employees within these schedules

```
var EmployeeScheduleRoles =
  (from esr in dbcontext.EmployeeScheduleRoles
  join s in schedList1 on esr.ScheduleID equals s.ScheduleID
  select esr)
```

I was hoping I could defer the first and have it execute WITH the second. It does this, but it runs "separately" as a subquery.

I've tried doing some inner joins to do this all at once, but I'm getting lost.

Desired Output:

```
EmployeeID  ScheduleID  RoleID
15921       1241        1
15927       1241        2
15948       1241        2
15949       1241        2
15950       1241        2
15951       1241        2
15952       1241        2
15953       1241        2
15954       1241        2
15955       1241        2
15956       1241        2
15957       1241        2
15958       1241        2
15959       1241        2
15960       1241        2
15961       1241        2
15962       1241        2
17822       1241        2
18026       1241        2
18027       1241        2
18028       1241        2
```

In this particular case, note that there is only one schedule for this account (within the manager's jurisdiction)

EDIT: I WANT TO GET RID OF 'schedList1' entirely and have it replaced by a join.

The following is functional, but I'd like to force this to happen in one query if possible rather than a main query and a subquery.

```
from esr in dbcontext.EmployeeScheduleRoles
join s in
  (from esr in dbcontext.EmployeeScheduleRoles
  where esr.EmployeeID == 15921 && esr.RoleID == 1
  select esr.ScheduleID)
on esr.ScheduleID equals s
select esr)
```

Comment: can you give exact output by combining the given to queries ? in table formate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
var EmployeeScheduleRoles =
  from esrManager in dbcontext.EmployeeScheduleRoles
  join esrEmployee in dbContext.EmployeeScheduleRoles on esrEmployee.ScheduleID equals esrManager.ScheduleID
  where esrManager.EmployeeID == 15921 && esrManager.RoleID == 1
  select new 
  {
     esrEmployee.EmployeeID,
     esrEmployee.ScheduleID,
     esrEmployee.RoleID
  };
```

You are joining the manager with his employees that share the same scheduleId, hence the appearence of EmployeeSchduleRoles twice.

Comment: Close, but see edit. I want to get rid of schedList1 because that's calling a separate (sub)query

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. There are no subqueries in my example.

Comment: I'm calling this against Entity Framework.
EF defers the schedList1 query to when the 'main' query is called, but I'd like to make this all one query.

Comment: The manager counts as an employee too (just a special one!) so no need to filter

Comment: I don't think you can avoid having two JOINS.  Entity Framework might try and generate SQL that uses a subquery rather than JOIN syntax, but SQL server's optimizer is smart enough not to care in most situations.

Comment: Of course, I definitely need two joins; there's no way to get around that.

I should clarify; EF is sending the schedList1 query as it's OWN query before the main query.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  I have seen LINQ to SQL do this, but not EF.

Comment: EF 4.0. FILLING SPACE HERE

Comment: Where is schedList1 coming from? Is it the same dbcontext?

Comment: Yes - the query is in the OP.

Comment: That works. I'm an idiot, actually; the subquery was unrelated (ish) :( Thanks!